# Internal Microphone is not working on the latest ubuntu 20.04.1LTS in acer swift 3

Tags: xubuntu, linux-headers

I installed ubuntu 20.04.1LTS in acer swift 3 .The internal microphone is not working.The system sounds are working fine.

Comment: Can you please add more details about hardware (microphone) ?

Answer (score 1):

Similar bug affects multiple users and multiple laptops, there is some information with probable solutions for it in this thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1840725
Unfortunately there are no fixes which would have worked for me yet, I also have an Acer Swift 3 SF314-57G.

The bug is now fixed in latest kernels. Here you can find all the information: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1877757